# Update MS Dynamics 365 records with email metrics data from Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: dynamics-365, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am working on an integration project between Salesforce Marketing Cloud and MS Dynamics 365. The scope is to capture email engagment activities such as open, click and sent in SFMC and write them into MS D365. On my research, I found there is an entity called elcn__core_emailservicemetrics in D365. When using this entity, I am unable to associate the email with Contact records in D365.

1. What is the best practice to achieve this?
2. I found out there is _ownerid_value but I could not write back the contact ID into the field. I am getting "CRM do not support direct update of Entity Reference properties, Use Navigation properties instead" Error when I tried to write the Contact ID.

Please help,

I am expecting to have the email metrics data for SFMC to be written in D365

Answer (score 0):

Your question is 2 part .

1. Dynamic part - i am not much aware on it
2. Salesforce marketing cloud part - On this side, you can use either automation studio to dump email metric in sftp as csv and then import it into dynamics. If you want to check in real time, you can use apis.